# Open a GUI in a Docker container running on a headless machine

Tags: xorg, vnc, docker, container

I'm trying to open Firefox GUI on a Docker container.
I'm avoiding most common solution which seems to use at one point `/tmp/.X11-unix` from host because I want the container to work on any host, including a headless host without X11.

The goal is just to use selenium to open Firefox GUI and take a screenshot.
I'm not quite sure if it possible but I guess it is.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get -y update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get -y install python3 python3-pip firefox-geckodriver x11vnc xvfb
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get -y install x11-xserver-utils
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir pip-with-requires-python && \
    pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir --prefer-binary selenium

WORKDIR /app

COPY entrypoint.sh .
COPY script.py .

RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

CMD ["x11vnc", "-create", "-forever"]
ENV DISPLAY :0
CMD ["xhost", "+"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Currently xhost ouput `xhost:  unable to open display :0`. I'm not sure about the `:0` but I tried several values.

Selenium of course also fails with:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

I'm running out of ideas so anything would be appreciated :)
I'm probably missing an important part.

Comment: You're not going to start a GUI that depends on X11 without X11 running *somewhere*. You could start Firefox itself in a headless mode and ask it to take the screenshot or whatever, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/48377879/2072269